# If you decide to play for "top or bottom" in duplicate, are you supposed to consult with partner?

Tags: bridge, ethics

Sometimes, if a player falls behind in a duplicate tournament, he will try to alter his standing by doing things that the "crowd" would not (e.g. making safety plays), getting a top score if he is right, and a  bottom score if he is wrong. This is unusual behavior, because he is really playing "double or nothing."

Bridge is a partnership game, and partners are supposed to agree on things. So should one consult with partner about "risking a limb to save a life" in this manner during play? On the hand, if one is doing certain other things such as "psyching," even *partner* isn't supposed to be on the secret. So is this a "consultation" or a "psyching" situation?

Or is it best to consult with partner *before* the tournament (but not during) about when to play for "top or bottom."

Answer (score 1):

It's neither - it's simply terrible bridge. Good bridge is to make those choices during the play instead of during the bidding, when one actually has enough information to make a sensible risk assessment.

Further, you are talking about a change in partnership bidding style - this is simply not allowed during a session, and the meaning of a call is not allowed to vary depending on which partner makes it:

> from [***Law 40 A - Players' Systemic Agreements***](http://www.acbl.org/acbl-content/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Laws-of-Duplicate-Bridge.pdf) (**my emphasis**)
>
> ***2*** Information conveyed to partner through such understandings must arise from the calls, plays, and conditions of the **current deal**. Each player is entitled to take into account the legal auction and, subject to any exclusions in these Laws, the cards he has seen.
>
> from [***Law 40 B - Special Partnership Understandings***](http://www.acbl.org/acbl-content/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Laws-of-Duplicate-Bridge.pdf)
>
> ***1(b)*** Whether explicit or implicit, an agreement between partners is a partnership understanding. ....
>
> ***2 (a)***... the meaning of a call or play shall not alter by reference to the member of the partnership by whom it is made.

Remember, the opponents don't know whether you are having a good, bad, or indifferent game; but partner does. To make decisions based on that information, which partner is privy to but the opponents not, is blatantly violating the requirement that opponents have a right to full disclosure of your partnership agreements.

So, if one feels compelled to take a flyer late in a session, one should do it as Declarer when there is no issue of Partnership Agreement. Adopt a second best line of play and cross your fingers. Play for the finesse missing Qxxx, or the drop missing Qxxxx, and see if it works. If one wants to be an improving player, one has to play like one.

Comment: Surely this is way too simplistic a view.  Over the course of a bridge session, there are certainly going to be some marginal decisions which one might make one way or the other, and there is no doubt that how one thinks one is doing has some subconscious influence on them.  There have certainly been sessions of bridge where I started swinging - not a lot - but stretching a point or two in competition or bidding game hoping for near perfect cards from partner - without actually realizing it at the time.  It can easily start from around the 10th board of 24 playing weak NT in the US.

Comment: So the essence of cheating is making technically inferior plays, and getting superior results, because the Bayesian information set has been illegally altered, right? And if I or Alexander made these "top or bottom" plays without illegal signals, we wouldn't necessarily be considered cheaters, but would run the risk of being tagged as inferior players.

Comment: @TomAu:No, the essence of cheating (in this regard at least) is undisclosed partnership agreements; that is why the Law excerpts in my answer are from **Law 40**. The difficulty in this case arises from the undisclosed (and improper) manner in which your partnership agreements vary with your perception of results so far; information known only to partner.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Then "playing for top or bottom" is like a "psych" situation, where partner can't be in on the secret, right?

Comment: @TomAu: True - but understand the full consequences of this. You can't discuss doing so in a *post-mortem*, as a reason for a call, with anyone you may play with in future, as you announce an undisclosed agreement that that partner may remember in a future game. It is simply, for practical reasons, impossible to do this with any regularity without it becoming an undisclosed agreement - and if you don't do it frequently then it is pointless. There are countless better ways to improve your results than this red herring.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Thanks for your help. I do not expect to make the bad anti-queen plays that you mentioned, because that is irrational even in rubber (my "home") game, but I might end up making safety plays in duplicate because they are rational in rubber. Just not in duplicate. And when I talk about these behaviors, I'm thinking in terms of "one time, on my worst night." I wouldn't do this systematically like Cohen and Katz.

Comment: @TomAu: Don't discount those queen plays so readily - the *standard* line is only necessarily best *a priori*.  If you are counting the hand, you will have numerous opportunities over the course of a night to possibly go against the field because you are counting better (one hopes) than the field. There are many times where those plays **may be** the safety play, or otherwise warranted by the count available. Then you must judge what the *the field's* play is likely to be, and choose a line of play that maximizes your expected score..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32228/discussion-between-tom-au-and-pieter-geerkens).

Comment: It's true that changing one's bidding system in the middle of a session is not allowed (in the ACBL - other jurisdictions may differ), but it's not really possible, and no one tries, to legislate against subtle changes in partnership bidding style.  I certainly agree that the fact that partner is swinging should be disclosed, but I don't think an agreement to swing in the middle of a session is illegal - as long as it does not extend so far as to change one's bidding system.  Certainly in team games, taking unusual risks based on the state of the match is well accepted.

Comment: Here is an example for clarity.  Suppose I hold S: xxx H: Q D: KQTxx C: KT9x, and RHO opens 1 spade.  Even non-vulnerable, I probably wouldn't overcall 2 diamonds on board 1 against mediocre players, but I very well might if I thought I was already outclassed or if I thought we were hovering around 50% late or if I just had a double espresso.  Partner knows if any of those circumstances apply and should disclose it, but surely you can't mean I have to make a consistent judgement on that hand always.  (FYI, I'd quite likely overcall non-vul on S: xxx H: x D: KQTxx C: KQTx)

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: Formally, whether in the US or not, your partner is *required* either to behave as if your call meant exactly what it would have on board 1, or to explain when asked "partner may be overcalling light because we have had a bad session" (whether he should alert in order to do so would be a good topic for an Advanced Director's Training Course).  Both of these are difficult, so this behaviour (like most cases of unauthorized information) causes problems for your partner.

Comment: @TimLymington: It's not alertable since an agreement to overcall that light (it's still not *that* light) all the time is not alertable.  There have been a couple times I've asked "How sound are your overcalls?" and gotten the answer "Usually not too aggressive, but he just had a double espresso."  I just don't see the disclosure problem here, particularly if partner explicitly knows.  Frankly, we're talking about subtle differences that are impossible to get perfect disclosure on.  I'm sure you've wanted to know whether a specific 14 count would be upgraded to open 1N and found no way to ask.